# objective c start IBAction on application load/start automaticly

Tags: iphone, load, startup, ibaction

I have an IPhone app and want it to kick off an IBAction after it loads automaticly.

I have it set up for a button now. I am looking for some code to make this automatic on start up and then still use the button while in the application.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IBAction is just a normal method and you can just call it in a `awakeFromNIB`, `viewDidLoad`, `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` or similar method.